# Guid(Random ints) vs regular int primary key for chat application

Tags: database, performance, security, primary-key, guid

I am not asking a general "guid vs ints which is better" question. I know that, or atleast think I know that they both have specific scenarios where one is better than the other. But I do have a specific scenario where I am writing a chat application. I started the application with all my primary keys being ints. But after doing a bit of research I realized that I might be having a security flaw in the application as I am passing the primary key to a user's browser for different entity requests such as chatrooms, talkers and such. One would agree that a subsequent primary key could be guessed and hence it is possible for users to alter other users sessions and states. In trying to prevent this, I was considering using guids as my primary key but then another thought hit me. A thought about performance. Since this is a chat application, is using a guid really going to cost me performance-wise if the application comes under heavy load, say 10s or 100s of thousands of users simultaneously for e.g. I am not really informed enough to make a choice here. My question in short is, do I need to change my primary keys to guids to help make guessing primary keys harder or is there some other way that I could secure my application without resorting to guids. If the question is not clear enough, let me know and I will clarify, thanks.

Comment: Here am I thinking that a GUID **is** an int, albeit one with more bits than most programming languages provide for integers and one which is generally represented in hexadecimal form.  Is the nub of your question really about the choice between random IDs (such as uuidgen might generate) and sequential IDs ?  If it is, why not say so ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark...Thanks for the information, I should have clarified...but yes thats what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

No you don't need to change your primary key to GUIDs.  This will not necessarily give you any additional security and it is arguably [security by obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Using GUIDs makes it infeasible for an attacker to guess another user's ID, or a chatroom's unique key.  However, it doesn't stop them seeing the IDs if they're transmitted and then being able to perform whatever action you're currently worried about.

Instead, when a user makes a request on the database you must validate whether they are allowed access to that data.  For example, they should only be able to retrieve their own user information, or basic user information about other users (such as handle, but not e-mail address).